# Error retrieving XML Data via XMLHttpRequest in Windows8 App

Tags: windows, xmlhttprequest

So I am trying to retrieve an rss feed in a synchronous call like so:

```js
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", topicsUrl, false);
    oReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    oReq.send();
```

The Send throws a Network Error, but did at one stage work.  This is a cross domain xhr request that needs to be synchronous.  I have tried to use the onreadystatechange between the header and the send but it didn't help.  If I use an Asynchronous call the return data parsing starts before there is any data returned?  So I'm a little puzzled how I can get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needs to respond to your request with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. You sending it from the client does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that very obviously